# Between dynamic dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So part of my query, I would like to filter the results to show just the ones between a set date range, however, that date range is dynamic, based on an event.

For example:

```
WHERE date d
   BETWEEN '2017-01-01'         -- just a sample fixed date
   AND DATEADD(D, CONTACT_DATE, -1) -- to show a day before Contact Date
```

Basically just trying see if there was another CONTACT_DATE this year, excluding the day of the actual contact.

I know there could be other ways to do this, but I was wondering if I can tweak a query with the current logic.

ERROR:

> Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd
>   function.

Comment: You're simply missing `BETWEEN .... AND ...`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo from my end. I have the between and just included the `AND`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed the parameters. 
The syntax is this:

```
DATEADD (datepart , number , date )
```

You should change it to this:

```
DATEADD(D, -1, CONTACT_DATE)
```

See here the docs:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186819(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Embarrassing. Got it mixed with my DATEDIFF. I'm getting 0 results now, but at least not error. Got to refine my logic better. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
DATEADD(D, -1, CONTACT_DATE)
```